# Destruir Canvas para reutilizarlo

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

Un saludo, estoy usando `char.js`, para darle vida a unas graficas, llevo 5 en total en todas bien.
ahora intento hacer una mas dinámica con filtros de fechas pero me arroja un error.

**Uncaught Error: Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '2' must be destroyed before the canvas can be reused.**

este es el `script` que nos proporciona `Char.js` y utilizo para las graficas.

```
function GarficoConFechas(titulo,cantidad,tipo,encabezado,id) {
        
    var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: tipo,
    data: {
        labels: titulo, //titulo del bar
        datasets: [{
            label: encabezado,
            data: cantidad, //valores de las barras
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});

}
```

mediante un función le envió el **titulo, cantidad, tipo, encabezado, id**.

```
function GraficoTotalReproducidos5(){

    var fechainicio = $("#dt_fecha_inicio").val();
    var fechafin = $("#dt_fecha_fin").val();

    $.ajax({
        "url":"../controlador/dashboard/controlador_grafico_reproducidos_muertos.php",
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            fechainicio:fechainicio,
            fechafin:fechafin
        }
    
    }).done(function(resp){
        if (resp.length>0) {
            var data = JSON.parse(resp);
            var titulo = [];
            var cantidad = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                titulo.push(data[i][0]);
                cantidad.push(data[i][1]);
            }
            
            GarficoConFechas(titulo,cantidad,'pie','Cantidades Vendidas','grafico5');
        }

    
    })
}
```

como soluciono este error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que el problema viene porque la instancia nueva detecta que ya hay una previa usando el mismo canvas. La solución es destruir la instancia previa antes de crear la nueva. Para eso necesitarías que la variable myChart fuese global para poder acceder a ella en la segunda llamada:

```
let myChart;

function graficoConFechas(titulo,cantidad,tipo,encabezado,id) {
        
    var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d');
    if (myChart) {
        myChart.destroy();
    }
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, { ...};
}
```

Comment: Excelente, a quedado a la primera, muchas Gracias.

Comment: Estimado Pablo, muchas gracias por esa respuesta, me sirvió, pero solo para 1 grafico. En mi código tengo muchas funciones que crean diversos gráficos, probé tu solucion y claro, me sirve, mi grafico se va actualizando mientras destruye el grafico anterior, pero todo esto se rompe al ejecutar mas funciones, tomando el mismo nombre del grafico como variable global... me podrías ayudar?